# Trust Level required for Membership Providers

Tags: asp.net

It seems that the trust level for the application is Minimal, this seems to create issues with my using the standard SQLMembershipProvider. Can anyone help me to understand if this is a limitation of the SQLMembershipProvider, or the fact that I only have Minimal trust?

To put it another way, is it possible to use the Membership/Role Provider infrastructure in Minimal trust? or do I need to use a different approach for authentication/authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it should be possible to work with the SQLMembershipProvider in minimal trust.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx

```
[AspNetHostingPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal)]
[AspNetHostingPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal)]
public class SqlMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
```

As you don't indicate what issues you're having though so it's not possible to identify what is wrong.